# WifiPermissionsUtil Denied on React Native

Tags: android, react-native, wifi

I would like get Wifi list on React Native project, using react-native-android-wifi module.

But on my real device with API 27, i've an `WifiPermissionsUtil: Denied: no location permission` error on Visual Studio log.

My AndroidManifest.xml permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

It work on Android emulator (API 26) :

[image]

Anyone know if i need to add other permission for API 27 ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. you just need to add below code in your manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" 
android:required="true"/>
```

You need to turn on your device location: I used `react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box` library to turn on device location. It works.